# Configure role for Airflow Connection

Tags: connection, airflow

Is there a way to restrict Airflow Connections so that they're only visible to the a particular role?

In particular I would like a solution so that a user for a particular role can:

1. **Can only access** those connections that are assigned to their role
2. **Can only view** those connections that are assigned to their role

I have looked at the following page and there's no instructions there on how to accomplish this:
https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.1/howto/manage-connections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these restrictions through RBAC, but not to specific connections, it's all connections or none. To enable RBAC, you will need to either be version 1.10+ and set `rbac = True` under `[webserver]` as noted in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#new-webserver-ui-with-role-based-access-control. See the documentation for RBAC in https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#rbac-ui-security for more details on the feature.

The relevant permissions to you are `Connections` and `ConnectionModelView`. Then an extra step would be to use DAG level access to ensure certain users can't access DAGs that use certain connections (1.10.2+ only, see https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#dag-level-access-control-for-new-rbac-ui).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info @Daniel Huang.